# Number of elements in a ring such that $x^2=1$

Tags: ring-theory

How many elements,$x,$ in the ring $\mathbb Z/95 \mathbb Z$ such that $x^2=1?$

Hints please...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should ask whoever gave you the question what he/she means with $x^2$ if there is reason for doubt. However it should mean $x*x$.

Comment: I think there is only one element. $x=1.$ Is this correct?

Comment: No. There is at least another, 94. I reasoned this from noting that $x^2=1$ implies $(x-1)(x+1)=0$ and this is true if $x=-1=94$.

Comment: @sahab  in the ring $\mathbb Z/95 \mathbb Z,\ 19\times5=0,$ neither 19 nor 5 is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the actual problem, $\mathbb{Z}/95\mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$ and $-1 \mapsto (-1, -1) = (18, 4)$ under the natural isomorphism, so you can solve the problem in $(\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z})$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$ separately, and then combine your answers to arrive at the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

A ring is said to have two basic operations defined on its elements; namely, addition and multiplication.

Unless explicitly mentioned, assume that $x^2$ is defined as the product of $x$ with itself inside the ring.

Thus, $x^2 = x \times x = 1$.

#### Hint

The notation $\mathbb{Z}/95\mathbb{Z}$ means a ring of integers modulo $95$. Thus, it will have the elements: $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, \cdots, 94 \}$

Comment: How to proceed to find such a $x?$

Comment: $x\cdot x \equiv 1 \mod(95)$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2$ is usually taken to be $x*x$.